# Error with my controller and ajax function

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I used AJAX to create live search function, but I have meet the error on my controller. I think it's syntax error on the last td @method('DELETE'), I don't know how to fix it, can anyone help me ?

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $output = '';
    $users = User::where('name','LIKE','%'.$request->keyword.'%')->get();
    foreach($users as $user)
    {
        $output += '<tr>
        <td>
            <div class="d-flex px-2 py-1">
                <div>
                    <img src="'. asset('storage/users/' . $user->image) .'"
                        class="avatar avatar-sm me-3 border-radius-lg" alt="user1">
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
                    <h6 class="mb-0 text-sm">{{ $user->name }}</h6>
                    <p class="text-xs text-secondary mb-0">'. $user->email .'</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="text-xs font-weight-bold mb-0">'. $user->date_of_birth .'</p>
            <p class="text-xs text-secondary mb-0">'. $user->phone .'</p>
        </td>
        <td class="align-middle text-center">
            <span
                class="text-secondary text-xs font-weight-bold">'. $user->address .'</span>
        </td>
        <td class="align-middle">
            <form action="" method="POST">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                @method('DELETE')
                <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="tooltip"
                    data-original-title="Delete user" type="submit">Delete</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>';
    }

    return response()->json($output);
}
```

Comment: `@method(\'DELETE\')`

Answer (score 1):

One clean solution to achieve what you need is to render the HTML as blade file using `view('')->render()` instead of building it on the controller

Create a new view file at `resources/views/partials/user-search.blade.php` and move your HTML to it

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="d-flex px-2 py-1">
                <div>
                    <img src="{{ asset('storage/users/'.$user->image) }}"
                        class="avatar avatar-sm me-3 border-radius-lg" alt="user1">
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
                    <h6 class="mb-0 text-sm">{{ $user->name }}</h6>
                    <p class="text-xs text-secondary mb-0">{{ $user->email }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="text-xs font-weight-bold mb-0">{{ $user->date_of_birth }}</p>
            <p class="text-xs text-secondary mb-0">{{ $user->phone }}</p>
        </td>
        <td class="align-middle text-center">
            <span class="text-secondary text-xs font-weight-bold">{{ $user->address }}</span>
        </td>
        <td class="align-middle">
            <form action="" method="POST">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                @method('DELETE')
                <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="tooltip"
                    data-original-title="Delete user" type="submit">Delete</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

then modify your Controller `search` method to something like:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $users = User::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->keyword.'%')->get();

    $output = view('partials.user-search')->with(['users' => $users])->render();

    return response()->json($output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before I propose my fixes note that @ferhsom solution is a really a cleaner and better way to achieve what you need. But still the error in your code need to be pin pointed.

## Errors

### First the litteral string

Everything written between single quotes is considered as a string (literally) so no function call or variable will work.
The following string as HTML will give you this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxC8Z.png):

```php
'
<td>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        @method("DELETE")
        <button type="submit">Delete</button>
    </form>
</td>
'
```

But what you need is hidden inputs with the keys **_method** and **_token**.

### Second no Blade rendering

`@method` and `@csrf` are a Blade directives which will not make any sense if it doesn't pass through the rendering process.

## Solution

Replace `@method('DELETE')` with:

```php
'<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">'
```

For `@csrf` or `{{ csrf_field() }}` do:

```
'<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="' . csrf_token() . '">'
```

Or

```php
'' . csrf_field() . ''
```